# Invalid location 3,size is 3?

Tags: android, image, gridview, arraylist

In my android app I have a gridview that I want to show images from my sdcard. I stored the path of images in arraylist and now I want to show the image in the gridview by taking from uri from the arraylist.

This is my code :

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context MyContext;

        public GridAdapter(Context _MyContext) {
            MyContext = _MyContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            /* Set the number of element we want on the grid */
            //return listOfAllImages.size();
            return 20;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View MyView = convertView;

            listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
            String absolutePathOfImage = null;
            Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                    MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };

            cursor = BrowsePhotos.this.managedQuery(uri, projection, null,
                    null, null);
            column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index);
                listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
            }

            if (convertView == null) {
                /* we define the view that will display on the grid */

                // Inflate the layout
                // LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) MyContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

                // Add The Text!!!
                TextView tv = (TextView) MyView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
                tv.setText("Item " + position);

                // Add The Image!!!
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) MyView
                        .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
                iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listOfAllImages .get(position)));
            }


            for (int i = 1; i <=listOfAllImages.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Image" + listOfAllImages.get(position)
                        + "??");
            }


            MyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewImage.class);
                    i.putExtra("position", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            });


            return MyView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

In listOfALlImages I have all the path of images, but at line

```
iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(listOfAllImages .get(position)));
```

I got this in logCat:

```
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 3, size is 3
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at com.Xperia.BrowsePhotos$GridAdapter.getView(BrowsePhotos.java:134)
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1218)
07-27 10:12:15.211: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3896):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:265)
```

On sdcard I have 3 images.

Can anyone help me? I really don't understand where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `getCount()` method you should return `listOfAllImages.size()`.

The indexing is zero based. So get(0) return the first item, get(1) the second and so on.

Comment: I put listOfAllImages.size() but I get :  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-27 10:31:06.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5243):     at com.Xperia.BrowsePhotos$GridAdapter.getCount(BrowsePhotos.java:91)
07-27 10:31:06.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5243):     at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:128)
07-27 10:31:06.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5243):     at com.Xperia.BrowsePhotos.onCreate(BrowsePhotos.java:56)

Comment: you need to initialize your ArrayList inside the constructor of your Adapter not in the getView() method

Comment: you also need to put objects in your array in the constructor. Create a constructor that also takes as param an arraylist and add all items to Adapter array.

Comment: In DDMS not appear System.out.println() for nothing that I wrote in getView()

Comment: Sa fac un alt constructor pe langa cel care il am?

Comment: Yes create another constructor, and for logging in Android use android.util.Log and check the output in the LogCat console.

Comment: @Gabrielle let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1866/discussion-between-ovidiu-latcu-and-gabrielle)